# JavaScript Firebase Notifications Error Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, push-notification

I keep getting this error for few days on notifications part of my andriod project. The version of firebase tools that I use currently in npm is 3.9.1 not being the latest due to some issues.

**Error**

> Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a
>   non-empty string or a non-empty array.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
>       at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:130:23)
>       at Messaging.validateRegistrationTokensType (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:576:19)
>       at Messaging.sendToDevice (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:197:14)
>       at deviceToken.then.result (/user_code/index.js:36:32)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7

**CODE FROM HERE**

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

  const user_id = event.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);
  if(!event.data.val()){

    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {

      const token_id = result.val();

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: "Firend Request has sent you request",
          icon: "default"
        }
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification Feature');

      });

    });

  });
```